# Is it possible to install Robomongo on Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, robo3t

I could not find any binaries for ARM. Is there any alternative for Robomongo ?

Some pointers will help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using umongo. However who has linux version for mongo gui, you can use. http://edgytech.com/umongo/